# Batch Enable "Hide HDR Notifications on this device"

Tags: batch, windows-registry, notifications, hdr

I am trying to programmatically hide hdr notifications that recently got added to the xbox game bar in the last year or two. I tried enabling and disabling it through the ui and looking under these registry paths to no avail
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\GameBar` `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\GameDVR` `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\GameConfigStore` there is no new or changed setting when changing it from the ui.